# Bioshock 2 farming cash strategies

Tags: bioshock-2

Is there a simple way to farm cash in Bioshock 2?  I seem to run out of cash prior to the Big Daddy encounter.

Comment: What difficulty are you playing on? I have a full wallet all the time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, not really.  The best thing you can do is hang around a particular area for a while and kill off splicers.  Some of them will drop cash you can loot.  But even this isn't particularly efficient.

Answer (score 2):

In pauper's drop, take full advantage of the free drill fuel in the medical pavillion. Where the hotel collapses. Grab the research camera and find a few brute splicers to kill. Do not use the camera to complete the research. If your drill is fuel you should be able to kill it before it is empty. Return to the medical pavillon and rinse and repeat.